# Switch to TTYs without Function keys

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard, console

At the moment I have a keyboard which lacks function keys (F1 through F12), and I was wondering - is there a way I could switch to textual TTYs (and back, which might prove to be a problem if I were to use `xmodmap`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming Linux, you can use [chvt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chvt) (as in `sudo chvt N`) to switch virtual terminal, where `N` is the number corresponding to the VT to activate. For example, `sudo chvt 1` for the first VT, and `sudo chvt 7` for the VT where you will most often find X running.

Note that chvt requires root privileges to do its thing, hence the sudo is necessary unless you are already logged in as root.

On Debian, [chvt is provided by the packages `kbd` and `console-tools`](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=chvt&mode=exactfilename&suite=stable&arch=any); mine is the one from console-tools. Other distributions are likely similar.

By the way, this took me about 15 seconds to find by typing `linux remap virtual terminal switch` into Google. :-) I was expecting to find something to actually remap the switch to another key combination, but chvt answers your question just as well.