# Is a virtual console running as a process and implemented based on pseudoterminal?

Tags: linux, terminal-emulator, virtual-consoles, pseudoterminal

Linux has 7 virtual consoles, which correspond to 7 device files `/dev/tty[n]`.

Is a virtual console running as a process, just like a terminal emulator? (I am not sure. It seems a virtual console is part of the kernel, and if that is correct, it can't  be a process.)

Is a virtual console implemented based on pseudoterminal, just like a terminal emulator? (I guess no. Otherwise, a virtual console's device file will be `/dev/pts/[n]`, instead of `/dev/tty[n]`)

Thanks.

Comment: No, they're not ptys. But where did you get the idea that there's only 7 of them? `ls /dev/tty[0-9]* | wc -l` returns 64 on my system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is incorrect.

There's a terminal emulator program built into the Linux kernel.  It doesn't manifest as a running process with open file handles.  Nor does it require pseudo-terminal devices. It's layered on top of the framebuffer and the input event subsystem, which it uses internal kernel interfaces to access.  It presents itself to application-mode systems as a series of 63 (not 7) *kernel virtual terminal* devices, `/dev/tty1` to `/dev/tty63`.

*User-space virtual terminals* are implemented using pseudo-terminal devices.  Pseudo-terminal devices, kernel virtual terminal devices, and real terminal devices layered on top of serial ports are the three types of terminal device (as far as applications programs are concerned) in Linux.

Because of a lack of coördination, Linux documentation is now quite bad on this subject.  There has been for several years no manual page for kernel virtual terminal devices on several Linux operating systems, although there are pages for the other two types of terminal device.  This manual page would have explained the correct number or devices and their device file names and used to read:

> A Linux system has up to 63 virtual consoles (character devices with major number 4 and minor number 1 to 63), usually called `/dev/ttyn` with 1 <= *n* <= 63. The current console is also addressed by `/dev/console` or `/dev/tty0`, the character device with major number 4 and minor number 0.

Debian people noticed that Debian was missing a `console`(4) manual page in 2014, and switched to installing the one from the Linux Manpages Project, only for people in that same project to delete their `console`(4) manual page a year and a bit later in 2016 because "Debian and derivatives don't install this page" and "Debian no longer carries it".

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177209/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333922/5132
- [Linux: Difference between /dev/console , /dev/tty and /dev/tty0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/)
- [What are TTYs >12 used for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71168/)
- [`ttyS`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/ttyS.4.html). *Linux Programmers' Manual*.  Michael Kerrisk. 1992-12-19.
- [`pty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html). *Linux Programmers' Manual*.  Michael Kerrisk. 2017-09-15.
- https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/jessie/manpages/console.4.html
- https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/console.4.html
- https://dyn.manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages/console.4.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man4/console.4.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man4/console.4.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man4/console.4.html
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man4/console.4.html
- Vincent Lefevre (2014-12-27). *[manpages: some man pages have references to `console`(4), which no longer exists](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=774022)*.  Debian bug #774022.
- Dr. Tobias Quathamer (2016-01-05). "[`console.4`: Is now included in this package. (Closes: #774022)](https://sources.debian.org/src/manpages/4.16-1/debian/changelog/#L208)".  *manpages 4.04-0.1*.  changelog.
- Marko Myllynen (2016-01-07). *[`console`(4) is out of date](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110481)*.  Kernel bug #110481.
- Michael Kerrisk (2016-03-15).  "[`console.4`: Remove outdated page](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/commit/man4/console.4?id=0f9e6478e403b26c24ecaa6761bc53d05cf04265)". *man-pages*. kernel.org.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). "[Terminals](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/terminals.html)".  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). *[Manual pages for Linux kernel virtual terminal devices](http://jdebp.eu./Proposals/linux-kvt-manual-pages.html)*.  Proposals.

  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`console`](http://jdebp.eu./Proposals/console.html). *Linux Programmers' Manual*. Proposals.
  - Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). [`vt`](http://jdebp.eu./Proposals/vt.html). *Linux Programmers' Manual*. Proposals.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "The current console is also addressed by `/dev/console` or `/dev/tty0`". If I am correct, `/dev/tty` is the device file of the controlling terminal of the current process session. Are  `/dev/console`, `/dev/tty0` and  `/dev/tty` different? (2) Yes, there are `/dev/ttyn` with `1 <= n <= 63`.  When some says there are 7 virtual consoles in Linux, in what sense do they mean? Do they mean there are only 7 accessible by key shortcuts?

Comment: Well … _you_ said it, and only you to my knowledge.  When you said it, in what sense did _you_ mean?  (-:

Comment: I can switch to virtual console #2, by Ctrl-Alt-F2. May I ask how I can switch to virtual console #20?

Comment: You don't need my permission to ask a question.  (-:  But you'll probably see it speedily closed as a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333895/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82368/ , and their ilk.

Comment: You can be assured  that I am just acting polite by saying in that way. (:

Comment: My   recent posts are coming from my difficulty to understand the links you provided

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/485156/674 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/485204/674

Answer (score 0):

> When some says there are 7 virtual consoles in Linux, in what sense do
>   they mean? Do they mean there are only 7 accessible by key shortcuts?

In the sense that they are spawned / readily available. It *was* configured in `/etc/inittab`, by *spawning* several (a)gettys in a multiuser runlevel.

For once I cite [pideins](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html) (`getty.target` sends me there):

> By default this automatic spawning is done for the VTs up to VT6 only
>   (in order to be close to the traditional default configuration of
>   Linux systems)[1](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html)

One VT is often used for GUI - may count or not.

systemd does it more subtle, but the result is quite the same. An orthogonal feeling, especially when you use the arrow keys to flip through the ttys.

`chvt 20` puts me on a blank "terminal" (default systemd) -- it needs some getty to activate it first. Then you address it like that, or turn your Fn keys into an organ. Or use Alt-arrow.

> Is a virtual console running as a process

In a way yes. It needs a `getty` process to open a ttyX.

```
 6314 tty2     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty2 linux
 6316 tty3     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty3 linux
 7408 tty5     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty5 linux
 7453 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep getty
```