# Why can fprintf(stderr, ....) output to screen when stderr doesn't refer to a terminal device?

Tags: tty, init

Given that a simple program:

```c
/* ttyname.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char **tty = NULL;

  tty = ttyname(fileno(stderr));
  if (tty == NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  printf("%s\n", tty);
  
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

compile it as `ttyname` and invoke it as **init** , the result as following:

```
Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

which means that the error code is `ENOTTY`.
Why can fprintf(stderr, ....) output to screen when `stderr` doesn't refer to a terminal device ?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand. Are you asking why something can't output when there is no output?

Comment: I just think that if `stderr` doesn't refer to a terminal device it should not display result to screen...

Comment: This could be because you're using ttyname() wrong. `char *tty = NULL;`?

Comment: That is impossible. On error, ttyname() will return NULL.

Comment: Are you using systemd or some other init?

Comment: I make kernel directly invoke this program as init.

Comment: This link [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485156/what-is-dev-console-used-for](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485156/what-is-dev-console-used-for) is also helpful for me to figure out my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're invoking it as `init` then you're *not* getting output to the screen; the output is being sent to the kernel and the kernel is printing it to the screen.  `init` is a special process

You can think of this as similar to the following shell script:

```
$ x=$(ttyname 2>&1)
$ echo $x
Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

This is done via the `/dev/console` device; stdin/stdout/stderr for the init process are attached to this by the kernel.  Writes to that device are handled by the kernel and sent to the current console device(s), which may be the current vty or a serial port or elsewhere.

Comment: How do you know the output is being sent to the kernel ?

Comment: @LGD - see update on `/dev/console`

Comment: Ok, but I try to `readlink` of `/proc/self/fd/2` at init and the result is `/dev/console (deleted)`, what does it mean ?

Comment: The "(deleted)" part just means that file node is no longer visible (maybe switched root, or overlayed with udev devfs or something else); the original device was opened on rootfs (maybe initramfs or similar); see `console_on_rootfs` at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/init/main.c .  But because the process had the file open ('cos it was given it by the kernel) writes will still occur to the device (major 5, minor 1) even though it says "(deleted)".

Comment: A good reference, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `ttyname` is always going to fail when stderr is not a terminal. So in the case of stderr being a socket like potentially during boot, ttyname fails but you can write to stderr without a problem which is why the fprintf works.

You can get the socket name by doing what ttyname does and that is `readlink` on /proc/self/fd/FD with "FD" being 2 for stderr usually.

```c
  char tty[1024];

  ssize_t size = readlink("/proc/self/fd/2", tty, sizeof(tty)-1);
  if (size < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  tty[size] = 0;

  printf("%s\n", tty);
```

Comment: I run your program as init and get `/dev/console (deleted)` ...