# How to track a login console crash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, login, console, crash

I have a Jessie install that wont allow me to logon.

It boots up, presents the prompt, accepts the username and password, but just blinks and comes back to the login prompt.

It appears that `Bash` is getting an error code from some part of the login process, which causes it to exit back to the parent process.

How can I trace this. I have had a look thru all the regular `profile` and `rc` files (there is only one user besides `root`) but I can't see anything that might be causing it.

Because its happening inside `Bash`, its *NOT* putting anything in the system logs.

Is there a way to start/verify logging deamons, and what can I use to see what, where or why `Bash` is exiting after logging in.

I have access to the filesystem, so I can manually *poke* through it and make changes.

Comment: A few things, permissions or if you have `exit` on one of the rc files then yeah, that would prevent you from logging in.

Comment: ok, _permissions_ I had not thought of, but `exit` had occured to me. My last resort (which I have not tried yet) is to move all the fc files (maybe providing blank ones) and reintroduce then one at a time. thnx

Comment: @Jetchisel If the OP said "intermittantly wont allow" instead of "wont allow", would that change your response (because that was happening previously, before last upgrade)?

Comment: Do you have graphical or text terminal where you log on? The problems you describe look very typical XWindows crash, if you use graphical login. After login XWindows start, and if they crash you get back to login screen.

Comment: You aren't using the word "terminal" correctly, as clearly this _is_ terminal login.  Moreover, saying that this is the _console_ is saying something quite specific, that it is the console device, which probably is _not_ specifically the case here.  It is more likely that it is a Linux _kernel virtual terminal_ that you are talking about.  You are _not clarifying_ things to people.  Clarifications would mention the actual terminal device name (`/dev/tty1`?), mention whether this applies to both accounts, and mention how you are otherwise logging on in order to access the filesystem.

Comment: I just deleted a comment because I thought it was pointless, and the comment by @nobody may be of use to someone else in the future. FYI The linux source code calls it "console", go look. IE a terminal requires terminal emulation and by definition on TTY device, which is explicitly "a TeleTYpe _terminal_ device". If I were to concede to "console terminal" I would also have to accept the year as 1970. Remember that a printer is "an _output_ terminal", which is why "go sit at that terminal console" is accurate. In modern context a terminal is generally speaking an X Windows program that provides

Comment: You really do not understand the terminology, and are not clarifying things for people with this mis-use, let alone by omitting the other stuff.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484601/5132

Comment: .. a specific terminal emulation (eg XTerm). But technically that is not accurate, because FBTerm does _not_ run on X Windows, it runs on _the_ _linux_ _console_. If I was to agree with you, then I would have to say the other comment is also true, as both imply that I have lied by ommision, because I did _not_ mention any TTY# or X Windows running automatically after login. The truth is you are _both_ _wrong_ as I use a Frame Buffer device, and have presumed there is some missing information because I failed to specifically _exclude_ certain informaition. _CLEARLY_ neither understood the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `set -x` to the beginning of `/etc/profile`, causing the shell to display every command it is going to execute with all the variable expansions etc. already expanded, so you'll see what the shell is actually doing.

But if you're talking about a GUI login, first check that your filesystem is not 100% full: creating a GUI session requires creating a few small files, and if the filesystem is completely full, that will fail. A basic command-line login (e.g. over SSH or on the text-mode console) should succeed even when the disk is 100% full.

Comment: thnx, that may help debugging, line stepping would be the next helper (not available in any shell that I know of). The problem with that is the screen blank that happens before returning to the login prompt. Yes I originally thought it was a "disk" issue (full or inability to write, because its and sd-card). Because I _know_ it is failing in `bash`, I already know it will fail with `ssh` as well. I will 1st try your suggestion (a painful and time consuming process). However I could probably do that via `chroot` from another Jessie install, in which case it might not do the screen blank.

Comment: Check any `~/.bash_logout` scripts that might be applicable and comment out any "clear" commands for the duration of troubleshooting.

Comment: arh, thankyou. my feeling is that there is an error being printed, you just never get to se any text because the next thing that happens is a screen (terminal) `clear`.

Comment: The "`set -x` in `/etc/profile`" trick helped me understand why my session was crashing at login, thanks!